# Please correct my function to write an array of objects to a file

Tags: java, arrays, file, function, methods

Sorry if this question is extremely stupid but here it goes.  I am making a function / method (Can someone tell me which word is proper for Java?) and would like some help writing object arrays to files.  Below is my current code which results in a blank text file!  Please help!

```
public static void writelines(Object[] data, String filename, String extension) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        try {
            String fileid = filename + "." + extension;

            File file = new File(fileid);@SuppressWarnings("resource")
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            writer.println(data[i]);
        } catch (IOException writeFail) {}
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Open the file outside the loop, close it when you're finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your file creation happens inside the loop, you are re-creating the file for every single line of text. You should restructure your code to something like this:

```
        try {
            String fileid = filename + "." + extension;

            File file = new File(fileid);
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                writer.println(data[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException writeFail) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are creating new `FileWriter` each time you are trying to write something to file. By default `FileWriter` constructor resets content of file so this is your first problem. To solve it create it once before loop.

Second problem is that you are not closing your writer. So after you are done with writing all data to file use

```
writer.close()
```

or even better use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to close it automatically for you

```
try(PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File(filename + "." + extension)))){
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        writer.println(data[i]);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

Your last problem (well, maybe not actually problem but very bad habit) is that you are consuming exceptions. This code

```
catch (IOException writeFail) {}
```

will be source of many headaches in the future. Purpose of `catch` blocks is to handle problems not avoid them. If you don't know how to solve it then at least print informations about it so you know that there is still something you need to fix. So in worst case use

```
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```